# Access RDS (in VPC) from another account in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I want to create a connection of RDS in my lambda and RDS is in another account in VPC.
I have tried VPC peering for that but the CIDR is the same for both VPCs. Are there any other ways to access RDS from another account. VPC sharing is also not feasible because both accounts are not in the same organizations.

Comment: You'd either need to use VPC Peering, or access via the Internet. For this, the database would need to be set to `Publicly Accessible = Yes` and would need to be in a Public Subnet, with Security Groups permitting inbound access to the range of IP addresses used by AWS Lambda functions. Not great for security.

Comment: what about transit gateway. Does CIDR block overlapping or same also matter in this case?

Comment: From [Amazon Transit Gateway FAQs - Amazon Web Services](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/transit-gateway/faqs/): "Amazon Transit Gateway doesn’t support routing between Amazon VPCs with overlapping CIDRs."

Comment: What type of Amazon RDS database is it? If it is using Aurora Serverless, then you could [Use the Data API for Aurora Serverless - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html).

Comment: No, it is MySQL